# Like function with Ajax / PHP / jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

1 week ago, i decided to start adding AJAX and more jquery to my Website.
I think, the "combination" of PHP / Jquery / AJAX is the best thing ever.

Now i want to create a "like - system" in my community board. I did something similar already:

```
$(function(){
    $('.action-button.like').click(function(){
        //ajax part
        var articleId = $('.article-Id').html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: '/wiki/parts/likeArticle.php',
            data:  { 'articleId': articleId },
            //change button
            success: function (msg){ 
                $('.action-button.like span').fadeOut(400);
            },
            error: function (err)
            { alert(err.responseText)}
        });
    }); 
});
```

as you can see, the button / element disappears after a `click()` on it.
PHP data: the .php file "inserts the like" into the database ...

So - this works great ! 
Back to my question: After an user likes the post, i want to display a container with all users, which did this before.

I'm asking this, because i know how to do this / I have an Idea how i can realise my little project, but i dont know, if this is the propper way :)

My solution:

in $.ajax: 
I want to create a function on "success:" (and a new .php file, which loads all users / "likers")
the function uses `.load()` and loads the file, so everything should be done right, shouldn't it ?

I hope you understand my problem,
Greets :)

Comment: You can echo every html or things you want when calling the php function, and then append the data you've echoed, to a div on your page. Getting the echoed / reponse data from a php site is easy, that's already being sent to your "msg" variable in success: function(msg).
Maybe try to make an example of what you think your code could looks like, and then post it if you have issues, it's always good to start by your self, and learn by doing ^^

Comment: I don't really see the issue. Based on what you're describing your approach seems correct.

Comment: agree .. you have good approach for this

Comment: I always wonder why folks don't just try their idea and then come back here to ask questions if they run into an issue in doing so?  So, you're essentially just asking: "is this a good way to do it"?  You haven't showed the actual code you'd try, but conceptually it seems fine.  You make an ajax call to retrieve some content and insert it in the page.  Standard use of ajax.  You could save an ajax call if you added some arguments to the first ajax call so you could accomplish both in one ajax call (streamlining the networking).

Comment: because its 11:45 pm here and im too tried to start scripting now, but i already tried something like this, i was asking myself, how other people will handle my situation, thats why i postet :)